Android Open Accessory USB communication failing after closing and re-openning the android app
So i have an android app which communicates with a PC using AOA mode. The problem is when i close my app and re-open it i can send data from android device to PC but my listening thread does not work and receive any data, i have been searching the internet for answers but nothing helped my situation only workaround is to disconnect and reconnect the usb cable only after that my listener thread works again. Here is the code that i call in my apps onDestroy and also the code for initing the listener thread.
The function to close the accessory:
fun closeAccessory() {
        try {
            mInputStream?.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Error closing inputStream", e)
            logInfo(TAG, "Error closing inputStream")
        } finally {
            mInputStream = null
        }

        try {
            mOutputStream?.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Error closing outputStream", e)
            logInfo(TAG, "Error closing outputStream")
        } finally {
            mOutputStream = null
        }

        try {
            mFileDescriptor?.close()
        } catch (e: IOException) {
            Log.i(TAG, "Error closing fileDescriptor", e)
            logInfo(TAG, "Error closing fileDescriptor")
        } finally {
            mFileDescriptor = null
        }

        if (::readjob.isInitialized) readjob.cancel()
    }

The function to init the listener thread:
    private fun openAccessory(accessory: UsbAccessory) {
        mFileDescriptor = usbManager.openAccessory(accessory)
        if (mFileDescriptor != null) {

            mAccessory = accessory
            val fd = mFileDescriptor!!.fileDescriptor
            mInputStream = FileInputStream(fd)
            mOutputStream = FileOutputStream(fd)

            logInfo(Companion.TAG, "Accessory opened")


            readjob = GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO){
                isReading = true

                while (isReading) {
                    try {
                        val buffer = ByteArray(1000)
                        mInputStream!!.read(buffer)
                        getIncomingData(buffer)
                        logInfo(Companion.TAG, "Read succeed")

                    } catch (e: IOException) {
                        logInfo(Companion.TAG, "Read failed: $e")
                        break
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            logInfo(Companion.TAG, "Accessory open fail")
        }
    }

I have tried to not closing the inputstream but it made my connection unusable. Also i have tried to log the issue further with additional logs what i gathered from it: Accessory opens indeed and i can send data to PC but input stream is some what stucks in a corrupted state after closing so that i can not send data from PC to Android app i get a timeout.

But in AOA Android will be USB host, so your PC is acting as USB client? What USB protocol do you use in AOA mode? Does the component on PC side correctly recognizes that the app has ben closed?

I am using a lib-usb c++ program on windows to get the android device into AOA mode. And the connection works fine until i close and re-open the the accessory in android code otherwise i don't experience any issues with the communication. Even i cant use the android code to listen the inputstream, i can send data to PC app still using the outputstream and recieve it from to PC. Therefore i think my PC side code works fine. And i also use serial communication using TLV protocol if that was the initial question.

I would recommend to include the error message and stack trace you get when reopening your app. Also check logcat if it contains something about USB that might be related to your problem.

I can add the detailed log as well when i have access to my computer but to give information, i get read interrupted exception when calling the closeAccessory() and then when i re-open the app i get "Accessory opened" in the logcat so no error messages what so ever. When i try to send data from pc to android again. On the pc side i get bulk transfer error and my code times out. On the android side i basicly get nothing as if the reading thread is not working but i do know that reading thread is initilized properly and exacutes untill mInputStream!!.read(buffer) blocks it by the logs.

What Android devices (model name and Android version) have you tried? May be one manufacturer has implemented a bug and it works with others?

Migth be the case actually, i am using a POS machine and tried only with that device but you migth be right. I wanted to see if anybody experienced a similar issue or made something simillar and make it work so that maybe i can communicate with the manufacturer, if i can't find any solutions.

For development I would recommend to have a Pixel device as reference.
